# Why is not overloaded function for derived class object invoked when given a pointer to base class in C++?

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, overloading

In the following code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A {
  public:
    A() {}
    virtual ~A() {};
};

class B : public A {
  public:
    B() {}
    virtual ~B() {};
};

void process(const A&) {
    cout << "processing A" << endl;
}

void process(const B&) {
    cout << "processing B" << endl;
}

int main(void) {
    A* a = new B;
    process(*a);
    return 0;
}
```

the output of running it becomes

```
processing A
```

but I would have assumed that it should have been

```
processing B
```

since `a` points to the derived class `B` and not `A`. So why does it call the first implementation of `process` function and not the second?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The static type of expression `*a` is `A` because `a` was declared as

```
A* a = new B;
```

The compiler resolves the selection of overloaded functions using the static type of the argument.

Even when virtual functions are called the compiler uses the static type of the object to call appropriate function. The difference is only that the compiler uses the table of pointers to virtual functions to indirectly call the required function.

Comment: The type of `*a` is actually `A&`.

Comment: @iavr  From the C++ Standard: "If the type of the expression is “pointer to T,” the type of the result is “T.”

Comment: Instantiating `decltype(*a)::dummy()` results in `'decltype(*a)' (aka 'A &') is not a class, namespace, or scoped enumeration`. Same for `decltype((*a))`. Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: @iavr  You missed the quote of the Standard I cited.

Comment: @iavr  The compiler returns lvalue that is the same object as the original that is refered to. This reference has type T.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: I am afraid you used an incomplete quote from 5.3.1. You did not take into account the previous sentence. *[...] the result is an lvalue referring to the object or function to which the expression points. If the type of the expression is “pointer to T,” the type of the result is “T.”* The expression returns an lvalue *referring* to the object; that is, a reference.

Comment: @Gorpik In fact I said the same with other words.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make `process()` a `virtual` member function of `A`, `B`:

```
class A {
  public:
    A() {}
    virtual ~A() {};
    virtual void process() const { cout << "processing A" << endl; }
};

class B : public A {
  public:
    B() {}
    virtual ~B() {};
    virtual void process() const override { cout << "processing B" << endl; }
};

int main(void) {
    A* a = new B;
    a->process();
    return 0;
}
```

In your current code, `*a` is of type `A&`, so the closest match to `process(*a);` is the first overload (for `const A&`).

Answer (score 1):

`void process(const A&);` is a better (exact) match, since dereferencing `A*` gives you `A&`.

Short answer, but there isn't much more to say unless you want a reference from the standard.

You could `dynamic_cast` the result of `*a` and that would give you a `B&`, but that's smelly desing. What you probably want is a virtual function in `A` that's overriden in `B` (assume it's called `foo`). Then, calling `a->foo()` would dispatch to `B::foo`.