# Strange behavior on overriding methods and calling them with shared_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading, overriding, shared-ptr

For my collision code, I thought it would be neat if each entity overrode and defined its own interaction with any other entity.  So, I tried to implement this:

Entity.h:

```
class Bullet;
class Person;
class Entity
{
public:
    Entity();
    ~Entity();
    virtual void resolveCollision(Entity &other);
    virtual void resolveCollision(Bullet &other);
    virtual void resolveCollision(Person &other);
};
```

Entity.cpp:

```
void Entity::Entity() {}
void Entity::~Entity() {}
void Entity::resolveCollision(Entity &other) {
    std::cout << "collided entity with entity" << std::endl;
}
void Entity::resolveCollision(Bullet &other) {
    std::cout << "collided entity with bullet" << std::endl;
}
void Entity::resolveCollision(Person &other) {
    std::cout << "collided entity with person" << std::endl;
}
```

Person.h:

```
#include "Entity.h"
class Person :
    public Entity
{
public:
    Person();
    ~Person();
    void resolveCollision(Entity &other) override;
    void resolveCollision(Bullet &other) override;
    void resolveCollision(Person &other) override;
};
```

Person.cpp:

```
Person::Person() {}
Person::~Person() {}

void Person::resolveCollision(Entity &other) {
    std::cout << "collided person with entity" << std::endl;
}
void Person::resolveCollision(Bullet &other) {
    std::cout << "collided person with bullet" << std::endl;
}
void Person::resolveCollision(Person &other) {
    std::cout << "collided person with person" << std::endl;
}
```

Bullet.h (almost a replica of Person.h):

```
#include "Entity.h"
class Bullet :
    public Entity
{
public:
    Bullet();
    ~Bullet();
    void resolveCollision(Entity &other) override;
    void resolveCollision(Bullet &other) override;
    void resolveCollision(Person &other) override;
};
```

Bullet.cpp (almost a replica of Person.cpp):

```
Bullet::Bullet() {}
Bullet::~Bullet() {}

void Bullet::resolveCollision(Entity &other) {
    std::cout << "collided bullet with entity" << std::endl;
}
void Bullet::resolveCollision(Bullet &other) {
    std::cout << "collided bullet with bullet" << std::endl;
}
void Bullet::resolveCollision(Person &other) {
    std::cout << "collided bullet with person" << std::endl;
}
```

Finally, the main.cpp:

```
#include "Bullet.h"
#include "Person.h"
#include <typeinfo>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Entity>> entities;
    entities.push_back(std::shared_ptr<Person>(new Person()));
    entities.push_back(std::shared_ptr<Bullet>(new Bullet()));
    std::cout << typeid(entities[0]).name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << typeid(*entities[0]).name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << typeid(entities[1]).name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << typeid(*entities[1]).name() << std::endl;
    (*entities[0]).resolveCollision(*entities[1]);
    Person().resolveCollision(Bullet());
    return 0;
}
```

For some odd reason, the console outputs the following:

```
class std::shared_ptr<class Entity>
class Person
class std::shared_ptr<class Entity>
class Bullet
collided person with entity
collided person with bullet
```

So it seems to be recognizing that *entities[1] is a class Bullet, but for some reason, it calls the Person::resolveCollision(Entity) instead of Person::resolveCollision(Bullet) even though making instances of those classes and doing the same thing outputs a collision between a player and bullet.  What am I doing to cause this? Does the forward declaration cause this?

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is not overloaded function for derived class object invoked when given a pointer to base class in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22658316/why-is-not-overloaded-function-for-derived-class-object-invoked-when-given-a-poi)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The call

```
(*entities[0]).resolveCollision(*entities[1]);
```

resolves to `Entity::resolveCollision(Entity &other);` at compile time. By virtue of `virtual` function dispatch mechanism, the call is dispatched to `Person::resolveCollision(Entity &other);` at run time. However, the dynamic dispatch system does not change the call to `Person::resolveCollision(Bullet &other);` based on the run time information of `other`. That would require a [double dispatch system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch), which is not part of the language.

Comment: +1 for dropping the double dispatch mechanic or the lack thereof rather than quoting specifications about how virtual function calls are resolved at compile time.

Comment: Is there any solution to this other than trying to dynamically cast to every subclass to entity?

Comment: @Matthew, you can use [the visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) even though I find it distasteful.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the desired behaviour use the following piece of code :

```
auto bulletPtr = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<Bullet>(entities[1]);
if(bulletPtr)
{
    entities[0]->resolveCollision(bulletPtr);
}
```

entities[0]'s resolvecollision will call Person's resolveCollision as the function is virtual and overridden in the derived class. The c++ run-time has no clue that entities[1] is actually a bulletPtr, so you have to dyamically cast it down. You have to check for the validity of pointer returned by dynamic_pointer_cast.